# Error: DLL requires the use of native symbols

Tags: r, r-package

I am developing a small R package with a small bit of C code. I cannot share the full package itself, but I can share an even smaller package which reproduces the same error: https://github.com/wlandau/dllreprex. When  I run:

```r
dllreprex::hello()
```

I see:

```r
Error in dllreprex::hello() : DLL requires the use of native symbols
```

All obvious errors goes away when I comment out `R_forceSymbols(dll, TRUE);`, but I want to keep `R_forceSymbols()` if possible because leaving it out could be a security issue.

For completeness, my C code in `src/hello.c` is:

```c
#include <R.h>
#include <R_ext/Rdynload.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rversion.h>

SEXP hello(void) {
  const char *string = "hello";
  SEXP out = PROTECT(mkString(string));
  UNPROTECT(1);
  return out;
}

static const R_CallMethodDef call_methods[] = {
  {"c_hello", (DL_FUNC) &hello, 0},
  {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

void R_init_dllreprex(DllInfo *dll) {
  R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, call_methods, NULL, NULL);
  R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
  R_forceSymbols(dll, TRUE); // "DLL requires the use of native symbols"
}
```

My R code in `R/hello.R` is:

```r
#' @useDynLib dllreprex, .registration = TRUE
NULL

#' @export
hello <- function() {
  .Call("c_hello")
}
```

and my `NAMESPACE` is:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(hello)
useDynLib(dllreprex, .registration = TRUE)
```

Session info:

```r
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.4.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/Indiana/Indianapolis
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] dllreprex_0.1.0 compiler_4.3.0
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `.Call("c_hello")` with `.Call(c_hello)`?